# How to include a custom .jar file in a java gradle build?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a gradle project to build a .jar file from Java sources. Some of the classes it needs are in a separate .jar file (let's called it helper.jar). To build helper.jar there is an external build system that I can invoke via a shell script.

If I manually run the shell script first to create helper.jar, and then add the file as a top-level dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    implementation files('/path/to/helper.jar')
```

Then everything compiles ok.

I am trying to convert this to automatically run the shell script to build helper.jar if necessary. I removed the file from the dependencies above and tried adding this task:

```
tasks.register('buildHelperJar', Exec) {
    workingDir '/path/to/helper/root'
    commandLine 'build_helper.sh'
    outputs.file file('/path/to/helper.jar')
}
```

And then add it as a dependency:

```
project.afterEvaluate { proj ->
    tasks.findByName('compileReleaseJavaWithJavac').dependsOn('buildHelperJar')
}
```

This seems to invoke the `buildHelperJar` task ok (and helper.jar gets built ok) but the subsequent `compileReleaseJavaWithJavac` task fails with missing symbol errors for everything that should be in helper.jar. So it's like I'm not actually adding the jar file itself into the compile step. What should I be doing to achieve this? Thanks a lot

Comment: well your task only puts the file into that path, but gradle `dependencies` still is not aware of it

Comment: @Eugene thanks, could you tell me where to put the dependency and how to describe it? I can't put the path directly so need to take it from the task somehow

Comment: not sure if this will work, I can't test it right now, but can you try : `project.afterEvaluate { proj ->
    tasks.findByName('compileReleaseJavaWithJavac').dependsOn('buildHelperJar')
    dependencies.implementation files('/path/to/helper.jar')
}`